# Unable able to edit registered application in Application Manager in cpanel

Tags: cpanel

[image]

I'm registering a **node.js** application. I'm able to *initially register it*, but when I go to add an env for instance, and click deploy, I get this error. I'm not even sure where to start. I've been searching all over for what this error message can imply. Am I missing something?

Does it think this node.js application is a python application or something like that, is this a common weird error when setting up node.js? Am I missing a package?

Comment: Have you checked with your hosting company?  Perhaps it is a configuration issue.

Comment: They're not open until Monday, and they have told me in the past that some of this stuff falls under my responsibility (when it comes to cpanel). I wanted to make sure it's not something I'm supposed to fix or doing wrong. It lets me create the application, just not edit it - even if I just change the name by one letter. Correction. I called tech support, they said they don’t what it is, to call more advanced support when they open on Monday